# How to extract the style of the text including the value from text area using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the `textarea` for my web page.

It is similar to `RichTextEditor`.

Now i want to get the code for that text entered with its style and value of the text using JavaScript... so please can anyone help me.

I am able to extract only value but not style of the text..so how can I get the style also with text value...

Comment: what do you mean ... inline style attribute?

Comment: @Jishnu...i said its similar to RTE..i didnt say that i am using RTE..understand?

Comment: What do you think about starting to accept some answers?

Comment: can you post how is your style and what style do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style all by itself won't tell you what you want. You need to ask for a child of 'style'. Something like:

var textarea_style = getRefToDiv( 'id_of_the_textarea' ).style.the_style_attribute_you_want;

For example, style.fontWeight, style.lineHeight, and so on. BTW, the styles you set with CSS:

font-weight: bold;

in JS are named by deleting the dash and capitalizing the word after it, so in JS it's fontWeight.